# Read byte as binary from serial port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

How to i read the byte as binary instead of ASCII and write back as binary too?

```
private void ReadPort()
{
    while (_keepReading)
    {
        if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize + 1];
            try
            {
                int count = _serialPort.Read(readBuffer, 0, _serialPort.ReadBufferSize);
                String SerialIn = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer,0,count);
                DataReceived(SerialIn);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }
        else
        {
            TimeSpan waitTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
            Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong - but you _are_ reading it binary (the bytes), _then_ converting it to ASCII yourself?

Comment: did you mean to write `new string(buffer)`?? and what exactly do you mean by binary? There is no such datatype as binary

Answer (score 0):

When `_serialPort.ReadBufferSize` is specified and `_serialPort.Read()` is executed, until the received data reaches `_serialPort.ReadBufferSize`([At least 4096 bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)), it means that `_serialPort.Read()` waits or a `timeout exception` occurs.

Then does **write back** mean echoing back in binary to the same serial port that received it?

In the presented source code, the received data is `converted to an ASCII string` and passed to the `DataReceived()` function.

The processing and the question text do not match. Which is correct?
Or do you want to output the received data to the console or window text box?

Also, if you want to write back the received data, the function name `ReadPort()` is not appropriate because it represents only half of the processing.

Please clarify and detail what you want to do and add it to the question article.

---

For example, if you want to receive data from the serial port and echo back to the same port, the process would be:

```
byte[] Buffer = new byte[1];
TimeSpan waitTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
while (_keepReading)
{
   if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = _serialPort.Read(Buffer, 0, 1);
            if (count > 0)
            {
                _serialPort.Write(Buffer, 0, 1);
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException) { }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
    }
}
```